# I am new to JAXB. How can I merge two different xmls with different namespaces into one xml with a root element and unmarshal it?

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have a requirement to merge two xmls generated from two different SOAP calls. Both the XMLs have different namespaces in them. I used wsimport tool to generate JAXB compliant classes frm two sepearte WSDLs. One of the classes in each generated package has a "Response" object which has an API to to retrieve the root node / element from the XML. My code works when I unmarshal each single xml for e.g. below code works, but when I combine it with another xml which has different namespace and different root node, it will not work for some reason. I tried to create a @XmlRootElement Class CdmData {...} which contains getters to populate the data from merged XML after unmarshalling, however, it does not work. 
Can anyone help what is wrong with me code here?

```
try {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ContractRetrievalResponse.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    contractAppData = ((JAXBElement<ContractRetrievalResponse>) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(xmlFile1), ContractRetrievalResponse.class)).getValue();
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    Logger.error(ContractAppCdmData.class, "Error! System cannot unmarshal an xml file.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have merged below xmls into one xml called LoanContractMerge.xml.... The issue is, I am not able to unmarshal the merged xml. I tried to use @XmlElmentRoot and @XmlElementWrapper as well, but they didn't seem to be working for my code. Below are the details:

```
**XML 1:**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns3:SingleFamilyLoanFullViewResponse
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.somewebsite.com/loanApp/ws/messages" xmlns:ns2="http://www.somewebsite.com/cdm">
    <SingleFamilyLoanFullViews>
        <SingleFamilyLoanFullView>
            <SingleFamilyLoanSourcingData>
        ........
        ........
        <ns2:Loan>
            <ns2:LoanIdentifier>267731134</ns2:LoanIdentifier>
            <ns2:LoanMaturityDate>2045-01-01</ns2:LoanMaturityDate>
            <ns2:LoanPurposeType>Purchase</ns2:LoanPurposeType>         <ns2:LoanScheduledFirstPaymentDate>2015-02-01</ns2:LoanScheduledFirstPaymentDate>
            <ns2:MIDASLoanIdentifier>728254719</ns2:MIDASLoanIdentifier>
            </ns2:Loan>
            ........
            ........
        </SingleFamilyLoanSourcingData>
        </SingleFamilyLoanFullView>
    </SingleFamilyLoanFullViews>
</ns3:SingleFamilyLoanFullViewResponse>

****XML 2:****
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p1:ContractRetrievalResponse xmlns:p="http://www.somelocation.com/cdm"
    xmlns:p1="com/somelocation/contractapp/service">
    <p1:LoanPurchaseContractStructure>
        <p:ContractContainer>
    ........
    ........
    <p:Contract>
        <p:ContractDescription>p:ContractDescription</p:ContractDescription>
        <p:ContractEffectiveDate>2001-12-31T12:00:00
        </p:ContractEffectiveDate>
        <p:ContractExpirationDate>2001-01-01</p:ContractExpirationDate>
        <p:ContractIdentifier>41954028</p:ContractIdentifier>
    <p:ContractInitiatingDepartmentIdentifier>p:ContractInitiatingDepartmentIdentifier              
    </p:Contract>
    ........
    ........
    </p:ContractContainer>
    </p1:LoanPurchaseContractStructure>
</p1:ContractRetrievalResponse>

***Java Class:***
@XmlRootElement(name = "cdmData")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CdmData", propOrder = {
    "loanPurchaseContractStructure", "singleFamilyLoanFullViews",
    "errors"
})

public class CdmData {
    @XmlElement(name = "SingleFamilyLoanFullViews")
    protected SingleFamilyLoanFullViews singleFamilyLoanFullViews;
    @XmlElement(name = "Errors")
    protected ErrorList errors;
    @XmlElement(name = "LoanPurchaseContractStructure", nillable = true)
    protected List<LoanPurchaseContractStructure> loanPurchaseContractStructure;

    public SingleFamilyLoanFullViews getSingleFamilyLoanFullViews() {
        return singleFamilyLoanFullViews;
    }

    public void setSingleFamilyLoanFullViews(SingleFamilyLoanFullViews value) {
        this.singleFamilyLoanFullViews = value;
    }
    public List<LoanPurchaseContractStructure> getLoanPurchaseContractStructure() {
        if (loanPurchaseContractStructure == null) {
            loanPurchaseContractStructure = new ArrayList<LoanPurchaseContractStructure>();
        }
        return this.loanPurchaseContractStructure;
    }
}

**Class with unmarshal method:**

public class CDMDataFactory {
........
........
String xmlFileName = "LoanContractMerge.xml";

FileReader xmlFileReader = null;
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(xmlFileName);
try {
    xmlFileReader = new FileReader(url.getFile());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}                       }
CdmData cdmData = null;
try {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CdmData.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    cdmData = ((JAXBElement<CdmData>) jaxbUnmarshaller
            .unmarshal(new StreamSource(xmlFileReader),
                    CdmData.class)).getValue();
} catch (JAXBException e) {
    Logger.error(CDMDataFactory.class,
            "Error! System cannot unmarshal an xml file.");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
.......
.......
} //CDMFactory.java class 

I am not sure why I am not able to unmarshal the merged xml. When I use only one xml, it works as expected. Below  are the xsd files.

**XSD for XML 1:**
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="http://www.somelocation.com/loanApp/ws/messages" targetNamespace="http://www.somelocation.com/loanApp/ws/messages" xmlns:cdm="http://www.somelocation.com/cdm" version="1.0">
    <!-- <xs:include schemaLocation="LoanAPPRetrievalServiceBaseType.xs"/> -->
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.somelocation.com/cdm" schemaLocation="SingleFamilyLoanAPPStructure.1.0.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="LoanAppSmartSearchRequest" type="LoanAppSmartSearchRequest" />
    <xs:element name="SingleFamilyFullLoanViewRequest" type="SingleFamilyFullLoanViewRequest" />
    <xs:element name="LoanAppSmartSearchResponse" type="LoanAppSmartSearchResponse" />
    <xs:element name="SingleFamilyLoanFullViewResponse" type="SingleFamilyLoanFullViewResponse" />
    <xs:element name="LoanServiceRuntimeFault" type="LoanServiceRuntimeFault" />
    .................
    .................
    .................
    <xs:complexType name="SingleFamilyLoanFullView">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SingleFamilyLoanSourcingData" type="cdm:SingleFamilyLoanContainer" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="SingleFamilyLoanServicingData" type="cdm:SingleFamilyLoanContainer" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="SingleFamilyLoanFullViews">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SingleFamilyLoanFullView" type="SingleFamilyLoanFullView" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="SingleFamilyLoanFullViewResponse">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SingleFamilyLoanFullViews" type="SingleFamilyLoanFullViews" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="Errors" type="ErrorList" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="LoanServiceRuntimeFault">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="LoanServiceRuntimeFault" type="Fault_Type" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="Fault_Type">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="reason" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        .................
        .................   
</xs:schema>

**XSD for XML 2:**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.somelocation.com/cdm" xmlns:cdm="http://www.somelocation.com/cdm" targetNamespace="http://www.somelocation.com/cdm" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="6.0">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="cdm_ContractAPP.xsd"/>
    <xs:include schemaLocation="security_content.structure_v1.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="LoanPurchaseContractStructure" type="LoanPurchaseContractStructure"/>
    <xs:complexType name="LoanPurchaseContractStructure">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ContractContainer" type="ContractContainer" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ContractContainer">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" > 
            <xs:element name="Contract" type="Contract" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="ContractStatuses" type="ContractStatuses" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LongTermStandbyContract" type="LongTermStandbyContract" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ContractLoans" type="ContractLoans" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ContractAttributesContainers" type="ContractAttributesContainers" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="LoanPurchaseContractContainer" type="LoanPurchaseContractContainer" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="LoanServicingContractContainer" type="LoanServicingContractContainer" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" />
              <!--<xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" />-->
            <xs:element name="SecurityContentContainer" type="SecurityContentContainer" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ContractAttributesContainers">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ContractAttributesContainer" type="ContractAttributesContainer" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ContractStatuses">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ContractStatus" type="ContractStatus" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ContractLoans">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Loan" type="Loan" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ContractAttributesContainer">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ContractSequenceAttributes" type="ContractSequenceAttributes" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ContractAttribute" type="ContractAttribute" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="ServiceAttributeDefinition" type="ServiceAttributeDefinition" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="ContractSequenceAttributes">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ContractAttributeSequenceCount" type="FMNumberInt" nillable="true" minOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LoanPurchaseContractContainer">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LoanPurchaseContract" type="LoanPurchaseContract" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="LoanPurchaseContractPrice" type="LoanPurchaseContractPrice" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="SecuritySwapObligations" type="SecuritySwapObligations" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="LoanProductInstrument" type="LoanProductInstrument" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="LoanDeliveryObligation" type="LoanDeliveryObligation" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="SecuritySwapObligations">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SecuritySwapObligation" type="SecuritySwapObligation" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="LoanServicingContractContainer">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LoanServicingObligation" type="LoanServicingObligation" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="LoanServicingTerms" type="LoanServicingTerms" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Please ignore above typo - "it generated has met" :)

Comment: There's an edit link under your post that you can use to edit out typos and add additional information.  I took care of the typo for you, though, though it might not be approved before you get to it....

Comment: XSD 1 references `type=cdm:SingleFamilyLoanContainer` which it would appear to be expecting from  XSD 2 but I cannot see that type defined anywhere. In XSD 2.

Comment: Redge, thanks. Both the XSDs are different, and there is no relationships between them, meaning, these XSDs are from two different organizations.

Comment: Then why do you want to combine them?

Comment: Redge, We've a requirement to combine these two different xsds. The new XSD will be used to create JAXB classes and the purpose of doing this way is to generate an XML which can have the Root Element of XSD 1 and Root Element of XSD 2 under one Root Element. Once the XML is generated, we believe, we can easily unmarshal() it. Right now, my current solution is, marshaling each XML separately.  I am hoping to generate below sample xml once the XSDs are merged or imported one into another.

Comment: <CdmRoot> ...<RootFromXml1> <SomeElement1>...</SomeElement1> ..</RootFromXml1>                      <RootFromXml2>.....<SomeElement2>.....</SomeElement2> </RootFromXml2> </CdmRoot>

Comment: You could use the [Mergeable Plugin](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/Mergeable+plugin) to merge unmarshalled structures.